# Set custom keyboard shortcut scrolling mails up and down?

Tags: outlook

You can scroll down/up mails using up/down arrow keys. I would like to use j/k instead, is there a way to achieve this behaviour ? I haven't found anything unfortunately.
Thanks :)

Comment: Not out of the box. Programmatically, sure.

Comment: What would you suggest for programmatical approach ? :)